# New lines in Jasper Reports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, newline, line-breaks

I've just started using Jasper Reports to generate reports from data retrieved using Hibernate. Everything is working, except JR doesn't seem to respect newline characters (\n) in text fields. Is there a way to force line breaks at newline characters?

Answer (score 17):

Set the `isStyledText` to `true` (tick it) and to break the line use `<br/>`.

Example:

```
text + "<br/>" + newLineText
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use iReport, you can select the static text area. In the right column you will find the properties of that object. Under "Static text properties -> Text" you will find your text. Click onto the button [...] so that a window opens where you can enter your text including line breaks.

Answer (score 8):

if you use Static Text, in Jasper Studio, you can press Shift + Enter

Answer (score 5):

Set the markup as html then add a `<br/>`

Answer (score 3):

Set the text field expression as:

```
$F{..}+"\n"+$F{..}
```